# Microsoft Edge Block Scope Issue

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, microsoft-edge

The following code works perfectly fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Edge:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="listItems">one</li>
    <li class="listItems">two</li>
    <li class="listItems">three</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.listItems');
for (let i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    let element = listItems[i];
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert('Clicked on number: ' + i)
    });
}
```

When you click on the list items you get 0, 1, 2 respectively in Chrome/Firefox which is correkt. In Edge you get always the same number (exceeds the for-loop) which indicates that block scope isn't working. Any idea what is wrong with Edge or how to overcome this issue?

You can also test this in a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n9dp8sut/) in the respective browsers.

Comment: It's not an issue with block scope but with iteration scope, which is not supported in Edge < 14.

Comment: As stated by @zeroflagL, this no longer repros in recent builds of Edge.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a closure for it. This keeps the value inside of the function.

```js
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.listItems');
for (let i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    let element = listItems[i];
    element.addEventListener('click', (v => () => alert('Clicked on number: ' + v))(i));    
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="listItems">one</li>
    <li class="listItems">two</li>
    <li class="listItems">three</li>
    <li class="listItems">four</li>
    <li class="listItems">five</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Edge installed here to test with, but the same thing happens in IE11. Seems like it doesn't consider the variable declared in the `for()` as part of the block.

You can "fix" it (or work around it) like this:

```js
    var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.listItems');
    for (let i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
        let element = listItems[i];
        let j = i;    // <------ new variable
        element.addEventListener('click', function() {
            alert('Clicked on number: ' + j)
        });
    }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="listItems">one</li>
    <li class="listItems">two</li>
    <li class="listItems">three</li>
</ul>
```

That is, introduce a `let` variable that is inside the actual `{}` block. IE11 is definitely happy with that, so I hope Edge is too. (This saves you having to do it the old-school way with an extra closure in the loop.)

Comment: We have [free downloadable virtual machines](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) for Windows, MacOS, and Linux if you need access to Edge.